# Is there a way to get all values for a particular node?

Tags: 7, database

I would like to create a customized view and search page by writing my own module because I believe that Views is unable to do what I want.  This requires me to write my own SQL queries, as well.  Is there an API call I can use to get all the data and values about a specific node?  For example, if I had a content type that asked for your first name and last name:

```
$values = get_node($nid)
```

and $values would end up looking something like:

```
$values['first_name'];
$values['last_name'];
```

Right now, it seems that all the fields and values are in their own tables, which makes it a nightmare in writing my SQL query to gather all data about the particular node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) function.

eg:

```
 $node = node_load(nid); //you will get all fields values of particular node
 print_r($node);
```

Comment: for better formatting print "<pre>"; print_r ($vars); print "</pre>"; or you can also use debug($node);

Comment: Thank you!!!!  I knew the Drupal developers would think of this!